# Erro de compilação ao registrar informações em uma struct e uma substruct

Tags: c, self

Estou com um problema no meu código C. Meu objetivo é registrar categorias na minha primeira struct, o que ocorre sem problemas. Depois, eu quero registrar algumas subcategorias para cada categoria, o que causa o seguinte problema no código:

```
main.c|45|error: ‘(cate + (sizetype)((long unsigned int)i * 24))->sub’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?|
```

Acredito que estou me enganado com alguma coisa do ponteiro.

Aqui está o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct categoria_st{
    char * nome_categ;
    int num_subcateg;
    struct subcategorias_st * sub;
    };

struct subcategorias_st{
    char *nome_subcateg;
};

void le_string(char * buffer, int tam);

    int main(){
    struct categoria_st * cate;
    struct subcategorias_st * subcat;
    char aux[5000];
    int qtd_cat,i,k,tam,index=0 ,index2 = 0;

    printf("Quantidade de categorias que deseja cadastrar:\n");
    scanf("%d", &qtd_cat);
    cate = malloc(qtd_cat * sizeof(struct categoria_st));

    for(i=0; i < qtd_cat; i++){
        printf("Digite o nome da categoria:\n");
        le_string(aux, 5000);
        tam = strlen(aux)+1;
        cate[i].nome_categ = malloc(tam * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(cate[i].nome_categ, aux);

        printf("Digite o numero de subcateg:\n");
        scanf("%d", cate[i].num_subcateg);
        cate[i].sub = malloc(cate[i].num_subcateg * sizeof(cate->sub));
```

**essa parte acredito que não esteja correta.**

```
            for(k=0;k<cate[i].num_subcateg; k++){
            printf("Digite o nome da subcategoria:\n");
            le_string(aux, 5000);
            tam = strlen(aux)+1;
            cate[i].sub.nome_subcateg = malloc(tam * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(cate[i].sub[k].nome_subcateg, aux);
        }
        };

        while(index != 99){
        printf("Qual nome de categoria deseja vizualisar:\nEscolha entre 1 e %d:\n\n",qtd_cat);
        scanf("%d", &index);

        printf("Qual nome de subcategoria deseja vizualisar:\nEscolha entre 1 e %d:\n\n",cate[qtd_cat-1].num_subcateg);
        scanf("%d", &index2);

       printf("Nome da categoria eh: %s\nNome da subcategoria eh:%s\n", cate[index-1].nome_categ,cate[index-1].sub[index2-1].nome_subcateg);


           }

       return 0;
    };

    void le_string(char * buffer, int tam){
        do {
            fgets(buffer, tam, stdin);
        } while( strcmp("\n", buffer) == 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No trecho

```
cate[i].sub.nome_subcateg = malloc(tam * sizeof(char));
```

o elemento `.sub` é tratado como variável, mas o compilador reconhece um ponteiro.

```
struct categoria_st{
    char * nome_categ;
    int num_subcateg;
    struct subcategorias_st * sub; /* sub é um ponteiro */
};
```

Basta acrescentar `[k]` após `sub`, dessa forma:

```
cate[i].sub[k].nome_subcateg = malloc(tam * sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Recebi um ponto negativo pela pergunta. Você pode me ajudar a melhorar a forma com a qual eu perguntei?

Comment: Acredito que o problema seja o título: ele leva a entender que a pergunta se trata de como se realiza uma tarefa, enquanto que a pergunta está relacionada à solução de um erro de compilação.